# Erro 404 com Silex

Tags: silex

Fala galera, estou desenvolvendo um sistema para Web, não sei muito bem lidar com programação web, mas vamos lá:

Então, todos os meus controladores, index, htaccess, td certo, tanto que o projeto está funcionando normalmente se eu rodar ele localhost através do phpStorm (aquele códigozinho la "php -S localhost:8080 -t www")...

Porém quando envio este mesmo projeto para o FTP, o site abre normalmente, tranquilo, porém só abre a primeira página, se eu clicar em qualquer link ele da o Erro 404... Isso não acontece no localhost, so quando envio pra web. O estranho é funcionar normalmente a primeira página, é um sistema web para controle de caixa bem amador mesmo, so para meu uso, mas queria poder usar ele quando não estivesse em casa tambem...

[Acessem o site aqui](http://matheus-fluxo-caixa.atwebpages.com/) (tem até um vardump la kkkkk)

As pastas estão todas nos locais corretos, os caminhos estão todos certos, estou a 2 semanas com o problema e não achei nada na internet, realmente não sei mais o que fazer... Ta tudo certo, tanto que funciona local, to ficando louco ja...

Já até mudei de hospedagem, antes tava numa gratuita da Hostinger la... Agora ta na AgilityHoster, também gratuita. Como é um sistema so pra mim quero deixar na gratuita por enquanto...

O que vcs acham que pode ser? Valeu

PS: O projeto foi feito com Silex, naquele esquema de URL amigavel, onde através da url cai em um método "get" ou "post" dentro das classes...

Comment: Eu acho que a pasta `www` deve ficar na raiz para as coisas funcionar como você quer.